# How can I make a new netcdf file in a loop in bash?

Tags: bash, netcdf, nco

I am trying to loop over all the netcdf files in a certain directory with bash, manipulate them with NCO, and then write the result to new files, all with different names. I am thinking of something like this:

```
for f in *.nc 
do ncap2 -s "vt = vt*1.3" $f2$ 
done
```

The second line manipulates the variable 'vt'. The results should be stored in netcdf files with similar names as the ones that I'm looping over. So f.e., I want the manipulated file to be called test_m.nc if the original file is called test.nc.
The question is: what should I write instead of $f2$ to achieve this result?
Thanks!

Comment: Use ``"${f%.*}_m.nc"``

Answer (score 1):

This loops over the files and replaces the string `foo` in the input filename with the word `bar` in the output filename:

```
for f in *.nc 
do ncap2 -s "vt = vt*1.3" $f ${f/foo/bar} 
done
```

Another possibility is to create a counter outside the loop, increment it inside the loop, and include it in the output filename.